# Trying to stop a QThread gracefully, what's wrong with this implementation?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4, qthread

When running my code I start a thread that runs for around 50 seconds and does a lot of background stuff. If I run this program and then close it soon after, the stuff still goes on in the background for a while because the thread never dies. How can I kill the thread gracefully in my closeEvent method in my MianWindow class? I've tried setting up a method called exit(), creating a signal 'quitOperation' in the thread in question, and then tried to use

```
myThread.quitOperation.emit()
```

I expected that this would call my exit() function in my thread because I have this line in my constructor:

```
self.quitOperation.connect(self.exit)
```

However, when I use the first line it breaks, saying that 'myThread' has no attribute 'quitOperation'. Why is this? Is there a better way?

Comment: Please show the code that defines your thread class (including signal definition)

Comment: In general, providing a SSCCE will lead to much quicker help: it is much easier to troubleshoot a minimal complete working example. See http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for python, but I assume this `myThread.quitOperation.emit()` emits a signal for the thread to exit. The point is that while your worker is using the thread and does not return, nor runs `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`, `myThread` will never have the chance to actually process your request (this is called thread starvation).

Correct answer may depend on the situation, and the nature of the "stuff" your thread is doing. The most common practice is that the main thread sends a signal to the worker thread where a slot sets a flag. In the blocking process you regularly check this flag. It it is set you stop whatever "stuff" you are doing, tell your worker thread that it can quit (with a signal preferably with queued connection), call a `deleteLater()` on the worker object itself, and return from any functions you are currently in, so that the thread's event handler can run, and clear your worker object and itself up, the finally quit.

In case your "stuff" is a huge cycle of very fast operation like simple mathematics or directory navigation one-by-one that takes only a few milliseconds each, this will be enough.

In case your "stuff" contain huge blocking parts that you have no control of (an thus you can't place this flag checking call in it), you may need to wait in the main thread until the worker thread quits.

In case you use direct connect to set the flag, or you set it directly, be sure to protect the read/write access of the flag with a `QMutex` to prevent inconsistent reads, or user a queued connection to ensure single thread access of the flag.

While highly discouraged, optionally you can use `QThread`'s `terminate()` method to instantaneously kill the thread. You should never do this as it may cause memory leak, heap corruption, resource leaking and any nasty stuff as destructors and clean-up codes will not run, and the execution can be halted at an undesired state.